# xpinc Javascript no longer works after client downgrade

Tags: javascript, xpages, xpinc

I needed to downgrade my Lotus Notes client from 8.5.3 to 8.5.2 to verify some functionality works in the earlier client.  After doing this, any JavaScript included in my XPages, from a simple alert() prompt to the loading of Dojo, no longer works.  I've completely uninstalled 8.5.2, rebooted and reinstalled the client, to no avail.  Weird thing is, JavaScript does work in my Notes client in a simple page.

I've double-checked, and my Notes client preferences are set to run JavaScript, and my ECL entries show every legit signer as being able to run JavaScript.  The databases I've tested so far all have "Use JavaScript when loading pages" enabled.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: Did you reset the option to build the application in the lower version or is it still building as an 8.5.3 release?

Comment: Any errors in the log files (Help > Support > View Log and Help > Support > View Trace)?

Comment: @rrumaner It was originally set to build at the lowest version necessary to run the app.  I tried setting it to 8.5.2, but JavaScript still won't run.

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten no, nothing.  Which is odd.

Comment: I've found that my local web retriever process isn't working, either.  I've stopped my anti-virus, ZoneAlarm firewall and Windows Firewall, but it local web preview still won't work.  I'm running Windows 7, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Did you try and do a build in 852 designer. Maybe do a clean at the same time

Comment: How did you downgrade? Uninstall/Reintall? If so try the NICE tool instead (make sure to back up stuff you need). http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21459714

Comment: Check this article about what could be blocking local preview. http://www.tlcc.com/admin/Tips.nsf/0/449566F49D0C617A8525744100694725